# Error: could not find function "classify_emotion"

Tags: r, text-mining

I have been trying to do sentiment analysis for a random file. However the error thrown is :

```
could not find function "classify_emotion"
```

The package "sentiment" wasn't  available (for R version 3.1.2). However got the same installed through : `install_github('sentiment140', 'okugami79')`.

The error is still there : `could not find function "classify_emotion"`

The code:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(sentiment)
library(Rcpp)
skill <- read.csv("C:/Users/632579/Desktop/skill.csv", header=FALSE, comment.char="#")
df<- data.frame(skill)
textdata <- df[df$data, ]
textdata = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", textdata)
textdata = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", textdata)
textdata = gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", textdata)
textdata = gsub("http\\w+", "", textdata)
textdata = gsub("[ \t]{2,}", "", textdata)
textdata = gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", textdata)
try.error = function(x)
{
  y = NA
  try_error = tryCatch(tolower(x), error=function(e) e)
  if (!inherits(try_error, "error"))
    y = tolower(x)
  return(y)
}
textdata = sapply(textdata, try.error)
textdata = textdata[!is.na(textdata)]
names(textdata) = NULL
class_emo = classify_emotion(textdata, algorithm="bayes", prior=1.0)
emotion = class_emo[,7]
emotion[is.na(emotion)] = "unknown"
class_pol = classify_polarity(textdata, algorithm="bayes")
polarity = class_pol[,4]


sent_df = data.frame(text=textdata, emotion=emotion,polarity=polarity, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
sent_df = within(sent_df,emotion <- factor(emotion, levels=names(sort(table(emotion), decreasing=TRUE))))
ggplot(sent_df, aes(x=emotion)) +
geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=emotion)) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") +
labs(x="emotion categories", y="")

ggplot(sent_df, aes(x=polarity)) +
geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=polarity)) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdGy") +
labs(x="polarity categories", y="")
emos = levels(factor(sent_df$emotion))
nemo = length(emos)
emo.docs = rep("", nemo)
for (i in 1:nemo)
{
  tmp = textdata[emotion == emos[i]]
  emo.docs[i] = paste(tmp, collapse=" ")
}
emo.docs = removeWords(emo.docs, stopwords("english"))
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(emo.docs))
tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
tdm = as.matrix(tdm)
colnames(tdm) = emos
comparison.cloud(tdm, colors = brewer.pal(nemo, "Dark2"),
                 scale = c(3,.5), random.order = FALSE,
                 title.size = 1.5)
```

Comment: I can't find that function on github either. Can you point me to where it has been introduced.

Comment: I think it is not the same package you found on github. You can install `sentiment` package for cran archive or found the right github repos

Comment: Try to install the `RTextTools` package

Answer (score 0):

You should consider updating to the current version of R, update your packages, and see if that doesn't solve the issue. Consider using the "installr" package to update.

The function is located [here](https://github.com/timjurka/sentiment/blob/master/sentiment/R/classify_emotion.R) if you're looking to directly load it.

Comment: tried it.....however now giving : Error in classify_emotion(textdata, algorithm = "bayes", prior = 1) : 
  could not find function "create_matrix"

Comment: Did you try directly loading the function or updating R? create_matrix is another function in the package that would also need to be directly loaded. I encourage you to update R and then attempt to install the package with install.packages("sentiment"). 3.1.2 is outdated and many packages are not back-compatible that far.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same/similar problem. I had to separately install, RStem am tm packages first. Then install sentiment from disk. And then it worked fine.